# iOS: How to select your storyboard(Base) instead of storyboard(English)?

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, storyboard

So I turned internationalization on and the storyboards seems to have mixed up in the process and I have idea how to switch it back. Now I have two Main_iPad.storyboard.

The problem is when I update my storyboard(Base), nothing will be updated to the storyboard(English). And the english one is launched in my app.

Should I delete it the english one?

How to set the storyboard to base? I checked the plist and setting which storyboards to use is not language specific.

Possible to update one storyboard and it will update both?

Any advice would be grateful!